# Node optimization which causes wrong result?

Tags: javascript, node.js

*We've encountered a problem that happens randomly and I try to understand what's going on here. There's no need to understand what the code eventually do. the code is exactly the same except how we try to "truthify"  a specific value"*

[`Foo` and `Bar` (fiddle is here)](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/JPJeAyTfT0a) are  *exactly* the same functions.

Differences are here :

[image]

*(essentially, we're trying to "truethify" the `lsbValue`)*

We've tested it via this code (the same function runs on both `Foo` and `Bar` )

```
  function testGalois(fn) {
    const x = new Uint32Array([2425393296, 2425393296, 2425393296, 2425393296]);
    const y = new Uint32Array([3692772234, 3144594163, 3014792419, 2386452453]);
    const expected = [2793996538, 14267392, 3369100906, 2506634262];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      const result = Array.from(fn(x, y));
      if (JSON.stringify(result) != JSON.stringify(expected)) {
        console.error('Failed on iteration', i, 'expected', expected, 'result', result)
        return;
      }
    }
    console.log('Pass!');
  }
```

*`Foo` is running flawlessly everytime*.

However, `Bar` fails at a random iteration:

> Testing Foo
> Pass!
> Testing Bar
> Failed on iteration 64 expected [
> 2793996538, 14267392, 3369100906, 2506634262 ] result [ 4021467969,
> 3143765947, 1936448977, 785616812 ]

Let's run it again , now the error on different iteration :

> Testing Foo
> Pass!
> Testing Bar
> Failed on iteration 62 expected [
> 2793996538, 14267392, 3369100906, 2506634262 ] result [ 4021467969,
> 3143765947, 1936448977, 785616812 ]

Please notice that we're only after the truthy value of

```
 let lsbValue = !!(Vi[3] & 1 ) ; //fails at some iteration.
```

From my testing in `Bar`  :

```
   const lsbValue = !!(Vi[3] & 1 ) ;    //fails
   const lsbValue = Boolean(Vi[3] & 1 ) //fails
   const lsbValue = (Vi[3] & 1 )>0      //works
```

But then I thought that maybe there is some kind of shared resource being used here when trying to `Boolean` or `!!`  which led me to create `new Boolean(X)` at each iteration rather than `Boolean(X)`:

```
  const lsbValue = new Boolean((Vi[3] & 1 )).valueOf() ; //works !
```

**Question**

It smells like a shared initial location is being used when using `!!` or `Boolean`. ( although I know that `!!` is an operator.)

But then , creating a new instance per iteration , did the trick :
`const lsbValue = new Boolean((Vi[3] & 1 )).valueOf() ;`

Why do they yield different/wrong results?

[playground](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/JPJeAyTfT0a)

nb
*This doesn't happen in chrome. it happens only in node.*

Comment: Pictures of code, no information on the values when it _"fails at some iteration."_, link to an external resource instead of a snippet (or code block) in the question itself -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve] _in the question itself_

Comment: There is a code at the playground link and the picture ia just for diff visualize.  You clearly didn't read the question

Comment: I did. But you haven't read the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section: _"If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.** Use Stack Snippets to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."_

Comment: FWIW, this works correctly on node.js for ARM Linux (aarch64).

Comment: this is pretty strange.. whenever you make `Bar` take more time(like adding a console.log in the loop or pushing the result to an outside array), it consistently works.. maybe the `>` comparison is enough time to make it process the boolean correctly?? this question is strange ;-;

Comment: This is really weird, I played with the code and added some comments, it might help (https://www.mycompiler.io/view/7cnO56cQz6K). Still I have no idea what exactly can cause this.

Comment: Congrats, I think you've found a bug!  You can help by reporting a [Node.js issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues), but I bet it will be a v8 issue.  It seems to only be an x64 code-generator issue so far. Adding instructions near the initialization of `lsbValue` seems to shake some sense back into it. I couldn't figure out the root cause, but I suspect it's [deep in v8 codegen land](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/main/src/compiler/backend/x64/code-generator-x64.cc). There's still too much going on in your code for me to isolate it in the time I've spent so far.

Comment: @Wyck code doesnt matter here. they are the same "something" functions that suppose to emit same results.  it's just that one function does  ( example) : "1=2-1" and the other "1=3-2" , yet they yield different results. no need to know what the code actually does

Comment: The diff between the `--print-opt-code` output for the two on Node.js 17.3 (x64, macOS) isn't big, but it's obviously crucial somehow... https://gist.github.com/akx/ce18350bcce1335f6fdd272352f0fed6